# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'melt'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributeerror

I'm using python 3.6 on Jupyter notebook. I'm trying to use pandas melt method on a  simple 317x83 data frame called bshort. I'm using the following code for melting:

```
bmelt = bshort.melt(['artist','track','time','date.entered'],['wk1','wk2','wk3'],'week','rank')
```

but I keep running into an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'melt'
```

I upgraded pandas but it didn't solve my problem. Any suggestion on how to make it work?

Comment: Try pd.melt(bshort)

Comment: `df.melt` was new in 0.20 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before pandas 0.20.0, `melt` was only a [pandas method, not a DataFrame method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html). If you have an older pandas, use `pd.melt(bshort,...)` instead of `bshort.melt(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pandas documentation, pd.melt() takes the object you want to use, as an argument.

Try this:

```
bmelt = pd.melt(bshort, ['artist', 'track', 'time', 'date.entered'],['wk1', 'wk2', 'wk3'], 'week', 'rank')
```

[Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html)